# List all .pfx files

Tags: android

I need to list all the .pfx files on the device.

I've tried using the code below:

```
String selectionMimeType = 
MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?";
String mimeType = "application/x-pkcs12";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{ mimeType };
Cursor cursor = cr.query(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), null, selectionMimeType, selectionArgs, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.TITLE));
    Log.i("Titulo",title);
}
```

But it does not work.
If I change mimetype to "application/pdf", the .pdf files are listed.

Why does not it work for .pfx files? Can someone help me?

Comment: `I need to list all the .pfx files on the device.`. Well than do it! Why are you asking the media store to do it for you?

Comment: @greenapps I thought I would need to use the MediaStore. But how can I do without it?

Comment: Recursively traverse the directories while listing the files in the directoried.